# Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have a Java class that uses Spark. I need to filter out the header from JavaRDD. This is how I want to do this.

```
String first = data.first();
JavaRDD<String> filteredData = data.filter((String s) -> {return !s.contains(first);});
```

However, this code `data.filter((String s) -> {return !s.contains(first);})` cannot be compiled. IntelliJ IDE says "Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level".

Comment: Change your project language level to 8.0.  Lambdas don't exist in JDK 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lambdas on Java 7, but it is a bit involved — you have to use something like [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda).

Also you can do the same thing without lambdas. Lambdas can be easily represented via annonymous classes, however it is a lot more verbose.

```
final String first = data.first();
JavaRDD<String> filteredData = data.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
  @Override public Boolean call(String s) {
    return !s.contains(first);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could I do a similar thing with Java 7?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I updated the answer.

Comment: What if I don't want to integrate any library in my project? Can I filter out a header using instruments of Java 7?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos answer updated

Comment: @KlausosKlausos probably you should also update your question with this requirements.

Comment: In this case, I assume that variable first must be global?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Oops, my bad. `first` should be annotated with `final` in order to be used in anonymous class.